# How to start SQL Server agent jobs automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, sql-server-agent

I am writing PowerShell scripts to control SQL Server agent start/stop to ensure all the contained jobs runs according to defined schedule. I want to make sure that the only thing I need to do is to start the SQL Server Agent Windows Service, and then all the contained SQL Server Jobs will run automatically according to defined schedule? No need to control each job's start/stop specifically?

I am using SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2003.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you start SQL Server Agent all jobs (if they are not disabled) will run automatically and it's no need to control each job. Just make sure that jobs are enabled.

Comment: Thanks HawX, do you have any documents to claim it? I have tested you are correct, and I want to read more to get more picture.

Comment: "Note: SQL Server Agent must be running before local or multiserver administrative jobs can run automatically." - quote from MSDN. You can read more about SQL Server Agent here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx

Comment: Agreed. That's how we run all of our database backups at our office.