# strange scripts generated by SQL Server when exporting a job

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I am using Management Studio -> Jobs -> Script Job as -> Drop and Create TO feature to generate related sql statement so that from another computer I can import the job.

My question is, from the generated sql scripts, from the beginning there is output like this, there is a hard coded jobid -- @job_id=N'3c5f83cd-e220-49ee-a1f1-40e37713ba1b'. My confusion is if we dependent on such hard coded value, on another computer maybe jobid is a different value... So importing into another computer may fail?

```
USE [msdb]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'TestCleanupJob')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_id=N'3c5f83cd-e220-49ee-a1f1-40e37713ba1b', @delete_unused_schedule=1
GO
```

EDIT1: here is the whole SQL Server scripts generated,

```
USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [TestJob]    Script Date: 08/03/2009 00:45:20 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'TestJob')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_id=N'20dbbd83-000f-489d-ad12-46be0c61bd3f', @delete_unused_schedule=1
GO

USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [TestJob]    Script Date: 08/03/2009 00:45:20 ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]]    Script Date: 08/03/2009 00:45:20 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'TestJob', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=3, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'Administrator', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [print]    Script Date: 08/03/2009 00:45:20 ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'print', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'pring "Hello SQL Server"', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'testschdeule', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=8, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
        @active_start_date=20090803, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'7c9dd61b-5bb9-4a9c-858b-114621f7fa6e'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

EDIT 2: here is my fix to use Job Name other than Job ID,

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'TestCleanupJob')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'TestCleanupJob', @delete_unused_schedule=1
GO
```

Comment: @George2: you make a good point, and I must say, I'm surprised - I would have imagined - like you, I guess - that when re-creating a job on another server, the same GUID would be used as JobID (would have made sense to me). Since that's not the case, I guess you really need to use the job name as the unique identifying key and create and delete your jobs based on the job name, rather than the unique Job ID.

Comment: NB: `Name` is not a unique column on table `msdb.dbo.sysjobs`; therefore you may have multiple jobs under the same name; `id` is however unique.  Since the `ID` column is a `uniqueidentifier` you won't get a clash with a job defined on another server unless you created the job using a script with a hardcoded ID; which you'd likely only do if importing a job as above; in which case it would likely be the job you're after anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @job_name parameter for sp_delete_job procedure instead of @job_id.

Comment: Yes, but it is automatic generated script by SQL Server Management Studio. My confusion is, if I use the script to import to another computer (and at the same time the job exists before on the computer), the related job_id may not be '3c5f83cd-e220-49ee-a1f1-40e37713ba1b'. Any ideas?

Comment: I have posted my fix to use job name other than job ID into EDIT 2 section of my original post, could you have a review whether my fix is correct please? :-)

Comment: Yes, its good. I tried to find a solution for your problem, but no luck. I think the only chance is to manually correct generated script. You can also use SSIS to transfer jobs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137568.aspx).