# Changing a Sql Job Dynamically

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job

I know how to create a job dynamically from this [create-sql-server-job-automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216584/create-sql-server-job-automatically)

The issue I have with this technique is clean up is required to delete all these jobs I create 
What I am looking for is a way to pass in a parameter to a Job or change a Job step dynamically

**Background**
I have a series of SSIS jobs I need a tester to run.  I was shot down in creating a webpage to call a WCF service that sits on the DB Server to execute the package.  I can not use xp_cmdshell.  So the third option was calling the package through a sql job.  Now while I can create one job per package ideally I would like one job where I can pass in the package name, a config file, and maybe some dynamic variables.

Looking at this post [Calling SSIS Package from Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008](http://3msoftwaretechnologists.blogspot.com/2008/12/calling-ssis-package-from-stored.html)
I can see how I create the dynamic package, again the concern is cleaning up the jobs.

**Constraints**
The reason I am going down the road of creating a job dynamically is a result of the following constraints

```
The testers do not have Sql installed on there machine so they do not have access
to the BIDS environment nor DTEXEC

For reasons not completely logical I am restricted from using c# and building a 
WCF service that would call the package through code

I can not use xp_cmdshell due to permission and security issues.
```

Now if there is a better way to handle this without Sql Jobs I am open to that possibility but the main goal is to create a form (web or windows) that the tester can choose a package, run it and see the internal logs of the package run that we record.

Comment: Are you looking to solve your base need (allowing a tester to run a series of SSIS packages) or are you looking for a solution to cleaning up dynamic jobs bit?

Comment: I guess the first, with the understanding that it can not be done with xp_cmdshell or .net

Comment: @Mike Why can't the testers install the SQL Server tools? If they are involved in any sort of technical testing they need the appropriate tools. I think your best solution here is to work on removing the constraints that prevent you and your tester doing your jobs efficiently. You've already suggested that these constraints are somewhat arbitrary, so if you haven't already done so, I would start documenting the time you and the tester spend on this task, to make it clear to your manager/customer that these constraints cost real money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters I proposed a 'cleaner' version on how to solve the question you linked too. Going from there it's only a small step to here : [sp_add_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079.aspx) where you'll find the explanation for `@delete_level`

```
Value Description
----- -----------
0     Never
1     On success
2     On failure
3     Always
```

So in short, if you want jobs to clean up after themselves, use @delete_level 1 or 3 according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks I did not see that the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have mixed up two questions here but since your real priority appears to be executing packages, why not use [dtexec or dtexecui](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138023%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)? Your testers can build them into a test script easily and that seems to be an easier solution than using jobs.

If this isn't possible for any reason then I think you will have to explain exactly what restrictions you have and why (possibly in a new question). Running packages is usually quite easy but it seems that you do not have a completely free hand to implement what you want.